# Directory.Exists return value for a user with no read/write permissions?

Tags: .net

Application lunched by a user with **no read/write permissions** to a specific folder. 
For example : "C:\Test".

If the application invokes `Directory.Exists("C:\Test")`, will the return value still be `True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx

If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory, the Exists method will return false.

Comment: And that seems a logical value to return, too; If the caller would have no access whatsoever, it might as well not exist. :)